# Is Red-Shift experiment correct?

Tags: energy, thought-experiment

I been reading: http://www.mth.uct.ac.za/omei/gr/chap5/node2.html. The website seems credible with its contact details & location being extremely accurate and easily verified, and its mathematics seem correct so I have no doubt about it however in this thought experiment it devises a object falling then

> observer has some magical method of converting all this energy into a photon of the same energy [ this is a thought experiment after all! ]

That seems slightly over-the-top expectations even for a thought experiment or is it perfectly credible and possible on contrary to my belief? 
I previously assumed thought-experiment had to be realistic yet this seems very un-realistic. Don't get me wrong I'm confident on this University and am sure that they have intelligent people but anyway is this though experiment for Red-Shift allowed even with its "magic" as some may call it?

Comment: It's not the best description, but it's basically saying that instead of a particle, you have a photon.

Comment: One can make things more realistic by assuming some fraction of the energy is converted into a photon. The Pound-Rebka experiment which verified the redshift predicted by this thought experiment is worth a read.

Comment: @suresh So would you say this thought experiment is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experiment is correct. Well, what is really correct is the final interpretation of the experiment. Radiation gets redshifted in the gravitational fields. It's one of the well-known consequences of general relativity. It's been known theoretical since 1915 or so and directly and safely experimentally verified in the 1960s.

All the "magic" terminology on the page is only meant to express the idea that the energy and the total relativistic mass must scale in the same way because they're related by $E=mc^2$, the well-known identity in special relativity.

Thanks to this identity, the conversion of matter into energy and vice versa isn't really "magical" in any sense. It may be done. When a particle (electron) and an antiparticle (positron) annihilate, they are indeed converted to a pair of photons. The gravitational potential may be used to accelerate the electron and positron against each other, for example, and the extra kinetic energy means that the annihilation will result in higher-frequency photons when it's done at a lower altitude, deeper in the gravitational field.

Because the energy conservation law says that it doesn't really matter whether we annihilate the electron-positron pair at a higher altitude, or we do so at a lower altitude, and transfer the photons back to the higher altitude, it follows that the photon has to lose some of its energy (the extra energy from the additional kinetic energy of the electron and positron) when it's flying up i.e. escaping from the gravitational field. That's the gravitational red shift.

The energy, total mass, as well as the frequency get reduced by the factor $\sqrt{g_{00}(A)/g_{00}(B)}$ between the points A and B.

Comment: So would you say this thought experiment is valid? even the "magic" part?

Comment: Yes, I would. I think that the "magic" words make it sound more controversial than it actually is but the beef is right.